# Поиск последнего вхождения в строке Jquery

Tags: jquery, регулярные-выражения

```
post[content_1537704579186][settings][code]
```

Нужно получать последнее слово в квадратных скобках, то есть `code` из строки.

Делаю так:

```
"post[content_1537704579186][settings][code]".match( /\[(.+?)\]/ig );
```

Но так я получаю три массива. Конечно я могу потом достать последний, о это не правильно. Вдруг элементов в скобках будет больше или мне нужно будет достать именно предпоследний.

Comment: что-то я не понял, вместо `code` у вас там произвольное значение или что? Если последний брать не хорошо, то на каком основании потом брать пред последний (когда будет больше элементов), или пред-предпоследний?

Comment: @teran вместо code любое значение. Мне просто нужно получить последнее найденное вхождение и только его.

Comment: Может, `.match( /\[([^\][]+)](?!.*\[^\][]*])/)`? Хотя, лучше `.match( /.*\[([^\][]*)]/)`

Comment: ну дак вы писали про предпоследнее в вопросе?

Comment: возьмите просто последний (не третий а последний) элемент из того что у вас находятся текущей регулярной или используйте `\[([^[]*?)\]$` для последнего элемента. в противном случае, не понятна задача

Comment: Ну так что, как? Что надо-то в конце концов?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew да, мне подошел Ваш вариант, забыл отписать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В регулярных выражениях поиск последнего совпадения в строке можно осуществить с помощью следующих шаблонов:
Если в строке нет переносов строк:

```js
шаблон_поиска(?!.*шаблон_поиска)
.*(шаблон_поиска)
```

Если в строке могут быть переносы строк:

```js
шаблон_поиска(?![\w\W]*шаблон_поиска)
[\w\W]*(шаблон_поиска)
```

В первом случае совпадение будет совпадать с ожидаемым результатом, во втором случае необходимо получить результат из первой подмаски.

## Вариант 1

```
/[\w\W]*\[([^\]\[]*)\]/
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/QFi8K1/1). Суть его в том, что сначала находится вся строка (`[\w\W]*` находит ноль и более любых символов), а затем индекс движется назад в попытке найти шаблон `\[([^\]\[]*)\]`:

- `\[` - символ `[`
- `([^\]\[]*)` - Захватывающая группа №1: ноль и более символов, отличных от `[` и `]`
- `\]` - символ `]`.

Пример кода на JavaScript:

```js
var text = "post[content_1537704579186][settings][code]";
var rx = /[\w\W]*\[([^\]\[]*)\]/;
console.log((m=text.match(rx)) ? m[1] : "");
```

## Вариант 2

```
/\[([^\]\[]+)\](?![\w\W]*\[[^\]\[]*\])/
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/bCflDZ/1).

Тут смысл в том, что после того, как движок найдёт `\[([^\]\[]+)\]`, шаблон `(?![\w\W]*\[[^\]\[]*\])` (негативный блок предварительного просмотра вперёд) отменяет совпадение при нахождении ещё одной подстроки типа `[...]`.

```js
var text = "post[content_1537704579186][settings][code]";
var rx = /\[([^\]\[]+)\](?![\w\W]*\[[^\]\[]*\])/;
console.log((m=text.match(rx)) ? m[1] : "");
```

Comment: А так не проще - `/.*\[(.+?)\].*?$/` ?

Comment: @UModeL `.` не находит символов переноса строки.

Comment: @WiktorStribiew: ну, в примере вопроса и нет переносов.

Comment: @UModeL Я предлагаю общий вариант для всех NFA. Кстати, у вас выражение для `.replace`, а следует избегать таких шаблонов с `.*` в начале.

Comment: @WiktorStribiew: для `.replace` ? Т.е. не подойдёт для `.match` и с задачей не справиться?

Comment: @UModeL  В выражении для `match` не надо находить *целую* строку.